# In adaptive cards textinput how to mask password

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I am using adaptive cards in Bot framework for user Sign-In functionality.
How to mask the password in TextInpufield

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3102) - _"Password masking [in adaptive cards] is not currently a feature. We recommend using the Sign-in Card workflow."_

Comment: Like @stuartd mentioned above - it's not currently a feature of Bot Framework.

Comment: @NilsW it's not a feature of _adaptive cards_ - the sign-in card supports it.